# Getting stuck in an infinite-loop while retrieving api result

Tags: java, rest

Getting stuck in an infinite-loop while retrieving api result.

Initialy I am getting scan percentage for 2-3 times but after that I am not getting any response.

My java code:

```java
int responseCode=200;
String responseText = "text";

while (!responseText.equalsIgnoreCase("100") && responseCode == 200) {

    URL urlForGetRequest = new URL("http://localhost:8090/burp/scanner/status");

    String readLine = null;

    HttpURLConnection conection = (HttpURLConnection) urlForGetRequest.openConnection();

    conection.setRequestMethod("GET");

    responseCode = conection.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("response" + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conection.getInputStream()));

    String response = "";

    while ((readLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response += (readLine);
    }
    
    in.close();
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
    // print result
    responseText = String.valueOf(jsonObj.get("scanPercentage"));
    System.out.println(responseText);
    TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(2);
}
```

output I got

```
response200
0
response200
4
response200
14
response200
17
```

and after this code kept on running without any output

Note: I perform get from its swagger UI,there is 1 error. i.e TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: why do you have new line char `"\n"` in the `urlForGetRequest`? Also the code is incomplete. Where is `responseCode` defined? Post the full class or function source code for anybody to help.

Comment: Connect a debugger and see what your code is doing.

Comment: @tgdavies no executable code found at     responseCode = conection.getResponseCode(); after some iterations.

Comment: @HossainKhan I have updated the quest

Answer (score 0):

There may be a chance the issue is in the response text check the actual text what the sender is sending

or just eliminate the extra space from the response text using following **oneline code before processing the response text**. It may be work for you if such problem is there..

```
responseText=responseText.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
```

Comment: but in the o/p it gave the last responseText value as 17. didn't feel this is the problem still will give a try

Answer (score 0):

You could try to check if it gets stuck in the `while` loop, by adding an output and see if it keeps writing when it gets stuck.

```
while ((readLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
     response += (readLine);
     System.out.print(".");
}
```

I don't think this is the reason but it is worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code in try, catch block and check what exception it's throwing.

Comment: No exception is there. But when I perform get from its swagger UI,there is 1 error. i.e TypeError: Failed to fetch